# In Jolt How to select based on jsonarray value

Tags: apache-nifi, jolt

In JOLT Based on the jsonarray values the output key and value should be added.
In the output CO2_VAL,CO_VAL,O3_VAL shoould come based on param value in env_values. So, how to apply the above filter.

The input payload is:

```
{
  "id":"abcd",
  "env_values":[
    {
      "param":"CO2",
      "values":"20.0"
    },
    {
      "param":"CO",
      "values":"21.0"
    },
    {
      "param":"O3",
      "values":"22.0"
    }

    ]
}
```

The output is :

```
{
  "sl":"abcd",
  "CO2_VAL":"20.0",
  "CO_VAL":"21.0",
  "O3_VAL":"22.0"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hope it is what you ment.  First of all, we are adding '_VAL' to the key. In the second spec we are putting keys to the values. And at the end we are pairing each key with value.

```
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "id": "s1",
      "env_values": {
        "*": {
          "param": {
            "*": "param[&2].t.&_VAL"
          },
          "values": "param[&1].values"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "s1": "s1",
      "param": {
        "*": {
          "t": {
            "*": {
              "$": "param[&3].key"
            }
          },
          "values": "param[&1].value"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "s1": "s1",
      "param": {
        "*": {
          "value": "@(1,key)"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```